How do I make Trino stop early when enough rows have been collected?
I have a Hive database and I am querying its tables through Trino. Every table has many partitions. Whenever I do a query like
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 100;

it still goes through all partitions first before returning 100 entries. Each partition has multiple hundreds of entries, so the computation should have halted after one partition and just given an output. But it does not, and when looking at the different UI elements, it appears to go through gigabytes of data before returning.
What configuration parameter do I need to tune to tell Trino to stop computations that have a LIMIT clause if it has gathered enough data? No configuration parameter in the documentation sticks out to me.

Your query does not specify what partition or how to limit the data .. so it must look at all the data and then cut down to 100 rows. It cant just randomly choose to return whatever.
If you want to reduce it to a specific partition .. just add a condition that limits that. Depending on your partition that could be some date value, or whatever else.
Also note.. just adding a sort wont help either since it then still has to look at all the data.

Thank you for the input. It sounds like something it should be able to do though. It is like short-circuiting while collecting rows, and allowing it to be coming from any partition. Maybe worthwhile to make a feature request to the trino-team.

Potentially yes ... it would still have to be reproducible so it looks easy on the surface only.

Fair enough :-)
